# LinkedList run time of line 5 in method shuffle

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, runtime

I wonder what the runtime of the the line list.set(i, list.get(j)); in big O notation is. Is it O(n^2) or O(2n). A linked list has a big O time complexity of O(n) for the get method and O(n) for the set method in java.

```java
public <T> void shuffle(LinkedList<T> list){               //(1)
     for(int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){                  //(2)
          for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){       //(3)
                T temp = list.get(i);                      //(4)
                list.set(i, list.get(j));                  //(5)
                list.set(j, temp);                         //(6)
```

I know that the out-most loop runs n times, the inner loop runs n-1 times. I am aware that when you have nested loops you multiply them (I concluded that from the rule of product from discrete mathematics, since the loops are independent of each other). Now the sum rule from discrete math told me that there are "A ways of doing something and B ways of doing another thing and we can not do both at the same time, then there are A + B ways to choose one of the actions".

However, I am not sure if what happens on line 5 for the get() and set() method can be considered independent or just not happening at the same time.

In other words, is the run time of line 5 O(n^2) or O(2n) = O( n + n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is O(n).

Firstly, O(2n) and O(n) is the same. It is unusual to write O(2n), but it is not incorrect.

The code in the line 5 call function get once. Third function gets the value. In the time of O(n) it gets the value of j-th element. After that, it calls set once, and by this function, in the time of O(n), it sets the value of i-th element.

So, its complexity is

2O(n) = O(n).

And if I may suggest, your algorithm is of complexity O(n^3). You could make it in O(n^2) if you use operations next and prev on iterator instead of iterating integers i and j.